# File-based CMS for single content type

Tags: cms

## Scenario

I am looking for a quick and easy solution to setup a simple CMS. I looked around at some candidates listed below, but found nothing suitable so far.

I want to only support a single content type for a certain type of content. For the sake of explaining it assume that I want to manage books. We are going to develop some custom add-on code for processing the book data managed by the CMS. The system is going to be deployed via docker and I would like to be able to build a final image that can be deployed into production.

## Requirements

The following requirements should be met:

- Runs as a docker container. I'd like to build a custom image including our extensions that is deployment-ready.
- Provides a form to create an entry for a new book and edit existing entries of books
- Lists all books and provides fulltext search through all data
- Needs to have some extension possibility to add custom code for reacting to entry modifications
- Free, preferably open-source

The following requirements would be nice, but are not strictly necessary:

- File-based storage
- LDAP support
- Versioning / Auditing of entry modifications

## Already considered

I already looked at the following options and found them to be lacking. I might be wrong on some of these of course.

- Plone: it's like throwing a nuclear bomb on a problem as big as a hairpin. It has everything needed above, but the setup and learning curve are just in another world.
- Drupal: seems to be hard to get a working docker instance for the full app. The standard image requires you to do all sorts of configuration and installation initially.
- grav: lacks LDAP support and apparently editing of existing book entries is hard
- pico: only hosts .md files, but no support for dynamic content creation

Comment: Providing fast full-text search is difficult if you have only file-based storage. Many ECM systems store everything in database. Some store the file blobs on the filesystem and the rest (content metadata, search index, user metadata, etc) in a database.

Answer (score 0):

## [NemakiWare](http://nemakiware.com/)

- Provides a form to add new "documents". You can customize document types (and their metadata) if you need.
- Lists all, with folder hierarchy
- Full-text search for supported file types
- Custom actions: Involves modifying some Java code.
- Docker has just been added (for now you need to build the Docker files but an image will be available soon): https://github.com/aegif/NemakiWare/tree/dockerize
- Free and Open source: GNU Affero General Public License version 3

From the "would be nice" section:

- Storage is done on CouchDB, not file-based
- [No LDAP support yet](https://github.com/aegif/NemakiWare/issues/67)
- Versioning is done, you can go back to a previous version
- Auditing: No

Screenshot showing metadata and version history on the left, and custom metadata on the right (in Japanese sorry):

[image: NemakiWare custom metadata]

Disclaimer: I work for the company that makes NemakiWare.